# Use of async and await to handle promise

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to use async and await to handle the promises. I would like to use this on the given example below:

```
exports.getUserData = async function(userId){
        let query = {};
        if(userId){
            query.where = {userid : req.query.id}
        }
        let data;
        try{
            data = await entity.DB_User.findAll(query);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

On execution its giving me an error

Error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: please provide more details of the code

Comment: What was the exception that wasn't caught?

Comment: keep your all code inside the method in a try block.

Comment: oh im not return data variable 
That's why error is comming

Comment: thanks to all for starting my help

Comment: You are passing a `userId` to the function and not passing it to where the query 

    if(userId){
      query.where = {userid : req.query.id} // userId instead of req.query.id ?
    }

Comment: You can `return Promise.reject(Error())` inside catch block

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, you should return `data`.

I think that the Exception is raised when you call `getUserData`. Try:

```
getUserData()
    .then(data => console.log)
    .catch(err => console.log) // this line prevent the UnhandledPromiseRejection

// or in async context

try {
    const data = await getUserData()
    console.log(data)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```